# Installing Deployd on Heroku with Mongolab

Tags: node.js, heroku, mlab, procfile, deployd

I'm very new to Heroku and deployd.

I managed to create an app and to create a mongoDBusing mongolab.
I inserted the 3 files (ProcFile, server.js and package.json => see code bellow) to the root of my heroku app folder

My app has application errors. Here are the logs, when I git push to heroku master (I wonder why it says that there is no ProcFile).

Could anyone help me with this?

**LOGS:**

> -----> Node.js app detected
>
> -----> Reading application state
>          package.json...
>          build directory...
>          cache directory...
>          environment variables...
>
> ```
>    Node engine:         0.8.x
>    Npm engine:          1.2.x
>    Start mechanism:     npm start
>    node_modules source: package.json
>    node_modules cached: true
>
>    NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
>    NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
> ```
>
> -----> Installing binaries
>          Resolving node version 0.8.x via semver.io...
>          Downloading and installing node 0.8.28...
>          Resolving npm version 1.2.x via semver.io...
>          Downloading and installing npm 1.2.8000 (replacing version 1.2.30)...
>          npm WARN package.json github-url-from-git@1.1.1 No repository field.
>          npm WARN package.json assert-plus@0.1.2 No repository field.
>          npm WARN package.json ctype@0.5.2 No repository field.
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob
>   requires minimatch@'^0.3.0' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minimatch,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.3.0
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob
>   requires once@'^1.3.0' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.3.0
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/inflight
>   requires once@'^1.3.0' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.3.0
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/init-package-json
>   requires glob@'^4.0.2' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.2
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks
>   requires semver@'^2.3.0' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.3.0
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client
>   requires graceful-fs@'^3.0.0' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.2
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client
>   requires npm-cache-filename@'^1.0.0' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-cache-filename,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.1
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmconf
>   requires ini@'^1.2.0' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ini,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.2.1
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmconf
>   requires osenv@'^0.1.0' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/osenv,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.1.0
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json
>   requires glob@'^4.0.2' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.2
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream-npm/node_modules/fstream-ignore
>   requires minimatch@'^0.3.0' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minimatch,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.3.0
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data
>   requires github-url-from-username-repo@'^0.2.0' but will load
>          npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/github-url-from-username-repo,
>          npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.2.0
>
> -----> Building dependencies
>          Npm version changed (2.2.0 => 1.2.8000); invalidating cache
>          Installing node modules
>          npm WARN package.json myappName@1.1.0 No repository field.
>          npm WARN package.json myappName@1.1.0 No README data
>          npm WARN engine deployd@0.7.0: wanted: {"node":">= 0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"v0.8.28","npm":"1.2.8000"})
>
> ```
>    > ws@0.4.32 install /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/node_modules/deployd/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
>    > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
>
>    make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/node_modules/deployd/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
>      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
>      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
>      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
>      COPY Release/bufferutil.node
>      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
>      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
>      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
>      COPY Release/validation.node
>    make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/node_modules/deployd/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
>
>    > bson@0.0.6 install /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f/node_modules/deployd/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
>    > node install.js
>
>    ================================================================================
>    =                                                                              =
>    =  To install with C++ bson parser do <npm install mongodb --mongodb:native>   =
>    =                                                                              =
>    ================================================================================
>    deployd@0.7.0 node_modules/deployd
>    ????????? scrubber@0.0.0
>    ????????? qs@0.6.6
>    ????????? validation@0.0.1
>    ????????? commander@2.6.0
>    ????????? corser@1.1.2
>    ????????? step@0.0.5
>    ????????? wrench@1.3.9
>    ????????? q@0.8.12
>    ????????? underscore@1.7.0
>    ????????? async@0.1.22
>    ????????? ejs@0.7.2
>    ????????? opener@1.3.0
>    ????????? semver@1.1.4
>    ????????? shelljs@0.0.6-pre2
>    ????????? debug@2.1.1 (ms@0.6.2)
>    ????????? cookies@0.5.0 (keygrip@1.0.1)
>    ????????? mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
>    ????????? filed@0.1.0 (mime@1.2.11)
>    ????????? send@0.0.2 (fresh@0.1.0, range-parser@0.0.4, mime@1.2.6)
>    ????????? fstream@0.1.31 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.5, rimraf@2.2.8)
>    ????????? doh@0.0.4 (ejs@0.8.8)
>    ????????? tar@0.1.20 (block-stream@0.0.7, inherits@2.0.1)
>    ????????? fstream-ignore@0.0.10 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
>    ????????? http-proxy@0.8.1 (colors@0.6.2, pkginfo@0.2.3, optimist@0.2.8)
>    ????????? request@2.51.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, caseless@0.8.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0,
> ```
>
> stringstream@0.0.4, oauth-sign@0.5.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, qs@2.3.3,
>   mime-types@1.0.2, node-uuid@1.4.2, combined-stream@0.0.7,
>   http-signature@0.10.1, tough-cookie@0.12.1, form-data@0.2.0, bl@0.9.4,
>   hawk@1.1.1)
>          ????????? socket.io@0.9.17 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)
>          ????????? mongodb@1.0.2 (bson@0.0.6)
>
> -----> Checking startup method
>          No Procfile; Adding 'web: npm start' to new Procfile
>
> -----> Finalizing build
>          Creating runtime environment
>          Exporting binary paths
>          Cleaning npm artifacts
>          Cleaning previous cache
>          Caching results for future builds
>
> -----> Build succeeded!
>
> ```
>    myappName@1.1.0 /tmp/build_eda7353fa1e9a8af28d45ba384d0c26f
>    ????????? deployd@0.7.0
>
>    WARNING: This version of npm (1.2.8000) has several known issues - consider upgrading to the latest release (2.2.0)
>    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-an-npm-version
> ```
>
> -----> Discovering process types
>          Procfile declares types -> web
>
> -----> Compressing... done, 11.1MB
>   -----> Launching... done, v12
>          https://[myappName].herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

**ProcFile**

```
web: node server
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "homepage": "",
  "author": "Me",
  "contributors": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "deployd": ">= 0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm":  "1.2.x"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
// require deployd
var deployd = require('deployd');

// configure database etc.
var server = deployd({
  port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
  env: 'production',
  db: {
    host: 'something.mongolab.com',//my real host name
    port: 31601,
    name: 'heroku_appxxxxxx', //my real app name
    credentials: {
      username: process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD
    }
  }
});

// heroku requires these settings for sockets to work
server.sockets.manager.settings.transports = ["xhr-polling"];

// start the server
server.listen();

// debug
server.on('listening', function() {
  console.log("Server is listening on port: " + process.env.PORT);
});

// Deployd requires this
server.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
  process.nextTick(function() { // Give the server a chance to return an error
    process.exit();
  });
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

**Here's what the "heroku log -t" command returns:**

> 2015-01-22T22:25:16.147815+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-22T22:25:16.878293+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 1 2015-01-22T22:25:16.890633+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
>   from starting to c rashed 2015-01-22T23:37:30.079428+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st arting
>   2015-01-22T23:37:32.332481+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `n pm start` 2015-01-22T23:37:34.519186+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-22T23:37:34.519203+00:00 app[web.1]: > myappname@1.1.0 start
>   /app 2015-01-22T23:37:34.519207+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-22T23:37:34.519205+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server
>   2015-01-22T23:37:35.071282+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-22T23:37:35.071937+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT, readdir
>   'resources' 2015-01-22T23:37:35.087520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   myappname@1.1.0 start: `node s erver` 2015-01-22T23:37:35.087700+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1 2015-01-22T23:37:35.087840+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! 2015-01-22T23:37:35.088495+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
>   ERR! This is most likely a prob lem with the myappname package,
>   2015-01-22T23:37:35.087892+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the
>   myappname@1.1.0 start script. 2015-01-22T23:37:35.091315+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app 2015-01-22T23:37:35.091657+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.8.28 2015-01-22T23:37:35.095021+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 2015-01-22T23:37:35.094749+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.8000 2015-01-22T23:37:35.101035+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! 2015-01-22T23:37:35.101194+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
>   ERR! Additional logging details  can be found in:
>   2015-01-22T23:37:35.101383+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   /app/npm-debug.log 2015-01-22T23:37:35.101550+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
>   ERR! not ok code 0 2015-01-22T23:37:35.071573+00:00 app[web.1]: Error
>   loading resources: 2015-01-22T23:37:35.089184+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
>   ERR! not with npm itself. 2015-01-22T23:37:35.081587+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-22T23:37:35.089921+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls
>   myappname 2015-01-22T23:37:35.090107+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There
>   is likely additional  logging output above.
>   2015-01-22T23:37:35.090358+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux
>   3.13.0-40-gen eric 2015-01-22T23:37:35.090869+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "node" "/app/.hero ku/node/bin/npm" "start"
>   2015-01-22T23:37:35.089349+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author
>   that this fails on your system: 2015-01-22T23:37:35.089535+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server 2015-01-22T23:37:35.089765+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via :
>   2015-01-22T23:37:35.914172+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 1 2015-01-22T23:37:35.922884+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
>   from starting to c rashed 2015-01-23T01:07:57.421508+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n pm start`
>   2015-01-23T01:07:59.976915+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-23T01:07:59.976963+00:00 app[web.1]: > myappname@1.1.0 start
>   /app 2015-01-23T01:07:59.976965+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server
>   2015-01-23T01:07:59.976967+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.496965+00:00 app[web.1]: Error loading resources:
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.507766+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.497357+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT, readdir
>   'resources' 2015-01-23T01:08:00.513161+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   myappname@1.1.0 start: `node s erver` 2015-01-23T01:08:00.513403+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1 2015-01-23T01:08:00.514599+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a prob lem with the myappname
>   package, 2015-01-23T01:08:00.513607+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.514719+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm
>   itself. 2015-01-23T01:08:00.513749+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed
>   at the myappname@1.1.0 start script. 2015-01-23T01:08:00.514853+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.496673+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.514977+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.515141+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get
>   their info via : 2015-01-23T01:08:00.515245+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   npm owner ls myappname 2015-01-23T01:08:00.515382+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional  logging output above.
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.515563+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux
>   3.13.0-40-gen eric 2015-01-23T01:08:00.515740+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "node" "/app/.hero ku/node/bin/npm" "start"
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.515914+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.516078+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.8.28
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.516321+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.8000
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.516461+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.517740+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   2015-01-23T01:08:00.517993+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   /app/npm-debug.log 2015-01-23T01:08:00.518222+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
>   ERR! not ok code 0 2015-01-23T01:08:00.517870+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
>   ERR! Additional logging details  can be found in:
>   2015-01-23T01:08:01.307216+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 1 2015-01-23T01:08:01.315931+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
>   from starting to c rashed 2015-01-23T04:15:56.955682+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st arting
>   2015-01-23T04:16:00.763097+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `n pm start` 2015-01-23T04:16:04.864921+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-23T04:16:04.864940+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server
>   2015-01-23T04:16:04.864942+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-23T04:16:04.864939+00:00 app[web.1]: > myappname@1.1.0 start
>   /app 2015-01-23T04:16:05.471847+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.452400+00:00 app[web.1]: Error loading resources:
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.476361+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.476484+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the
>   myappname@1.1.0 start script. 2015-01-23T04:16:05.477178+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.477054+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most
>   likely a prob lem with the myappname package,
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.477310+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author
>   that this fails on your system: 2015-01-23T04:16:05.452048+00:00
>   app[web.1]: 2015-01-23T04:16:05.452756+00:00 app[web.1]: Error:
>   ENOENT, readdir 'resources' 2015-01-23T04:16:05.475943+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! myappname@1.1.0 start: `node s erver`
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.476190+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.477973+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux
>   3.13.0-40-gen eric 2015-01-23T04:16:05.477435+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server 2015-01-23T04:16:05.477558+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
>   ERR! You can get their info via : 2015-01-23T04:16:05.477681+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls myappname
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.477804+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional  logging output above. 2015-01-23T04:16:05.478145+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "node" "/app/.hero ku/node/bin/npm"
>   "start" 2015-01-23T04:16:05.478311+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.478475+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.8.28
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.480171+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   /app/npm-debug.log 2015-01-23T04:16:05.480292+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
>   ERR! not ok code 0 2015-01-23T04:16:05.480111+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
>   ERR! Additional logging details  can be found in:
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.478856+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.8000
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.478967+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   2015-01-23T04:16:05.480021+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   2015-01-23T04:16:06.250211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 1 2015-01-23T04:16:06.261424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
>   from starting to c rashed

Comment: try command `heroku logs -t` to check app logs, since app is deployed successfully but it seems it crashes or something else happens when you hit app-url in browser. Copy app logs here for further understanding.

Comment: Thank you, I just added the heroku logs to the end of my message.

Comment: I see that the git push command says: "Checking startup method
No Procfile; Adding 'web: npm start' to new Procfile"  isn't it the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issues. :)

I needed to update the node and nmp version in **package.json**

`"engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm":  "2.2.x"
  }`

And I also had to create a "resources" folder in the root of my heroku app folder. 
Note that the resources folder, as it is empty might be ignored by git, so I added an empty file into it.

I hope it can help someone has I lost a couple of hours trying to solve these issues.